# Explanatory power of variables in multiple regression

Tags: regression, predictor, importance

Suppose that I have a regression model with two explanatory variables:

$$Y = b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + \varepsilon$$

The determination coefficient $R^2$ measures the amount of variability in the response variable $Y$ that can be explained by the explanatory variable. However, how can I find out the explanatory power that is exclusively attributable to each of the two explanatory variables as well as their common explanatory power?

I can think of the following approach. Orthogonalize $X_1$ relative to $X_2$ and call it $X_1^*$. In the following new model

$$Y = b_0 + b_1X_1^* + b_2X_2 + \varepsilon$$

I obtain the determination coefficient $R^2$ for $X_1^*$, which would be the unique explanatory power for $X_1$. Do the same for $X_2$.

Is this a reasonable approach? If yes, how can I obtain the common explanatory power for both $X_1$ and $X_2$? If not, do you have any solutions?

Comment: Maybe this one helps? http://biol09.biol.umontreal.ca/borcardd/partialr2.pdf

Comment: @coffeinjunky: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot...